# What could be the issue in my route that gets me MethodNotAllowedHttpException for my PUT, PATCH, DELETE and others routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8, laravel-7

Can you please help me with my issue. I am trying my best to fix the issue, but so far I have failed.

I even upgraded to Laravel 7.x with my application and still It kept on getting the same issue over and over again. Could my issue be in the user interface (UI)?

below are the errors that i'm getting:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The DELETE method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.
```

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.
```

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The PATCH method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD, POST.
```

This is my route

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    //return redirect(route('login'));
    return redirect()->route('login');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::middleware(['auth']) -> group(function() {

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::resource('/device', 'DeviceController'); 
Route::get('/laptops', 'LaptopsController@index')->name('laptops');

});
```

This is my form edit

```
<form action="/device" method="POST" id="editForm">
  {{csrf_field()}}
  {{ method_field('PUT') }}

   <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
   <label>Serial Number</label>
     <input type="text" name="Serial_No" id="" class="form-control"  placeholder="Enter Serial number">
   </div>

  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Add Data</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default float-right">Cancel</button>
   <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default float-middle">Clear</button>
</form>
```

This is my delete form

```
<form action="/device" method="POST" id="deleteForm">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            {{method_field('DELETE')}}

             <div class="form-row">
             <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="DELETE" >
             <P>Are You Sure!.. You want to delete this Device?</P>
             </div>

       <button class="btn btn-primary " type="submit" >YES! DELETE DEVICE</button>
       <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary float-right" data-dismiss="modal" >CANCEL</button>

      </form>
```

Comment: Show your route for which you get this error.

Comment: Can you show us the code that is responsible for making the request? And the routes you have defined?

Comment: You decide which methods a route accepts so if you want the route to accept `PUT` or `PATCH` or whatever you need to make it so

Comment: Definalty nothing related to UI...Please try harder, this is easy and answered on StackOverflow million times, if you look deeper you'll get it for sure. I believe in you.

Comment: @vivek_23 have added some code as suggested , check it out

Comment: For put and delete, I think you also need to add ID in the end of the form action attribute like `action='/device/2'`

Comment: why would i have to do that?

Comment: For Put or delete, you will also have to mention which one to delete or update. Did it work?

Comment: hope your eyes work very well

Comment: Why would you say that?